# JPanel resize and scroll errors

Tags: resize, scroll, textarea, jpanel

I use a text area with variable hight and some other things (a combo box in the sample code) filling the window width.
The following error happens:
- When using "innerPanel.setPreferredSize", the scroller does not appear when the text area becomes higher than the window by typing line feeds into the text area or when resizing the window vertically.
- When not using "innerPanel.setPreferredSize", (as shown commented in the sample code below), the used swing elements enlarge horizontally when resizing the window width, but do never shrink horizontally.

```
JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
JTextArea editArea = new JTextArea();
editArea.setLineWrap(true);
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.weightx = 1.;
innerPanel.add(editArea, gbc);
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
gbc.gridy = 1;
innerPanel.add(combo, gbc);
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(innerPanel,
  JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
  JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
//innerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
outerPanel.add(scroller);
frame.setContentPane(outerPanel);
```

Comment: I found a solution - it is ugly but it works:

Comment: With frame.addComponentListener(), listen to window resizing and within componentResized() do the following: save the text from the editArea and the state from other visible elements, then redraw the window using frame.setContentPane() and frame.validate(), and then restore the old contents to all the visible elements.

Comment: With this "solution", the code line innerPanel.setPreferredSize() is not needed.